# How to change default font in mit-scheme/edwin?

Tags: arch-linux

I am running `mit-scheme v9.0.1` on Arch Linux and I was wondering how I can change the default font for the `edwin` editor. Preferably I would like to use the same default font as `Emacs` uses.

I know about the `.edwin` file for customizing `edwin`, but I can't find any information on how to change the default font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place this in your `.edwin`:

```
((ref-command set-font) "9x15")
((ref-command set-frame-size) 163 90)
```

Also, [check this example config file](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/edwin-init.scm).

Comment: to get a list of all fonts available to edwin, go into edwin, do `M-x set-font RET` then hit `TAB`